# Finite $T_0$ spaces are sober

Tags: general-topology

A [sober space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space) is a topological space such that every irreducible closed subset is the closure of exactly one point.  Looking for examples I convinced myself that the following is true.

> Every finite $T_0$ topological space is sober.

As I could not find this mentioned anywhere, can someone provide a proof to have it as a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true. It suffices to show that every finite irreducible space has a generic point, since $T_0$ implies that generic points are unique. So, let $X$ be a finite irreducible space. Then $X$ is the union of the closures of its points, but this is a finite union of closed sets, so irreducibility says that one of these closures is $X$!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ is a finite $T_0$ space and $A\subseteq X$ is an irreducible closed subset.  Let $B\subset A$ be a maximal closed proper subset (which exists by finiteness), and let $x\in A\setminus B$.  By maximality of $B$, $B\cup\overline{\{x\}}$ must be all of $A$.  By irreducibility of $A$, this means either $B$ or $\overline{\{x\}}$ must be all of $A$, and thus $\overline{\{x\}}=A$ and $x$ is a generic point of $A$.

Comment: Very slick! I just want to point out that the $T_0$ assumption is necessary to deduce that the generic point of $A$ is unique.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming OP was aware that $T_0$ is equivalent to the "uniqueness" part of sobriety.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.  Finite spaces are quasi-sober (= every irreducible closed subset has a (not necessarily unique) generic point).